# Even using nsthread interface freezes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nstimer, nsthread

I have to perform a timer using a NSThread as I need to download text data from the web, and without that, in 3G connection it freezes the UI while downloading. So I've used a NSThread but it still freezes for a while and I don't know how to solve this....

Here's the code I'm using to perform the timer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(onTimerK2) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)onTimerK2{
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15 target:self selector:@selector(onTimerKY2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 [pool release];
}

- (void)onTimerKY2{
    NSLog(@"working");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're detaching a new thread to call `onTimerK2`, which then immediately calls a method back on the main thread, which will of course freeze your interface.

**Edit**

You should be doing any long-running work not on the main thread (either yourself, or by using the asynchronous nature of `NSURLConnection` as mentioned elsewhere),and then updating your UI by calling selectors on the main thread as this activity progresses.

Having said that, you may have more success with the following changes/reordering of your code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15 
                                             target:self 
                                           selector:@selector(onTimerK2) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)onTimerK2{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(onTimerKY2) 
                             toTarget:self 
                           withObject:nil];
}

- (void)onTimerKY2{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"working");
    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: ok, you're, so I've modified the code, but then the timer doesn't work anymore. see the first post please and thanks for answer

Comment: You need to configure run loop if you want to fire a timer from secondary thread.

Comment: Actually it doesn't call a method on the main thread.  The timer will be scheduled on the run loop of the new thread - which isn't being serviced, so the timer won't fire.

Comment: @JeremyP: The OP changed the code, it used to just call back into the main thread to schedule the timer. The freeze problem is obviously that the code downloads synchronously on the main thread.

Comment: that's great ! thank you so much, sorry, but I completely messed up with the code

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear how you are trying to solve the UI freeze problem by using timer. But if your UI is freezing due to downloading then you can try [asynchronous loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) instead of using timer or detaching another thread.

EDIT: Unless you configure a run loop for secondary thread, timer is not going to work from that thread. Check the [run loop management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) in threading programming guide. This can be a far difficult work than to use asynchronous connection.

Comment: I'm using a timer, because every 15 seconds I have to download data from an online txt where I grab some text

Comment: That does not prevent you from loading asynchronously.